# Is there an Arc type that can be moved (not shared) between threads?

Tags: rust

I have the problem of polling an `Arc`. As you see, the Arc is actually transfered to `C`. I do not use it anywhere after it is transfered to `C`. Since `C` must be `Sync+Send`, I cannot use a more simple container, so I use `Arc`:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use core::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::pin::Pin;
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead};

trait A{
    
}

impl AsyncRead for A {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}

pub struct C{
    c: Arc<dyn A + Send + Sync >
}

impl C {
    //Here we actually transfer/move our Arc<dyn A + Send + Sync >, 
    //we don't use it anymore on the other thread
    pub fn new(c: Arc<dyn A + Send + Sync >) -> C {
        C {
            c: c
        }
    }
}

impl AsyncRead for C {
    fn poll_read(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
        buf: &mut tokio::io::ReadBuf<'_>
    ) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        //since `c` is `Arc`, it has no interior mutability, so I cannot call `poll_read` on it
        self.c.poll_read(cx, buf)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a534ff22a572358223ead2925768bc71)

however, by using `Arc` I cannot do `self.c.poll_read(cx, buf)` because `Arc` does not provide interior mutability. In this case, however, I use `Arc` not for sharing between threads, but actually for sending `C` to other threads. If I simply did `Arc<Mutex<dyn A + Send + Sync>>` then it would work and I could poll with `self.c.lock().unwrap()poll_read(cx, buf)`. Since `C` is the only owner, it would block immediately, so no problem using inside `poll_read`, but is there a more elegant way of solving this problem?

Is there a type that can be sent to other threads in such a way that it is moved to that thread in such a way that it preserves interior mutability so I can poll it?

Comment: What's wrong with using a `Mutex` ? If you send something across threads, then you must make sure that it is not accessed by 2 threads at the same time. And that's exactly what `Mutex` is doing.

Comment: Note that [`Box<dyn A + Send + Sync>` is `Send + Sync`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Send), so if you are the only owner why not use that?

Comment: Seems to me, you have a syntax error, you have to call `poll_read` on a `Pin` type, so your last line should be: `self.poll_read(cx, buf)`, then it compiles